# Sencha Touch - Cordova, Text Input loses focus after first character entered

Tags: android, cordova, focus, sencha-touch-2, textinput

I am building a Cordova app for Android using Sencha Touch. The first time I enter a character in a text input field the focus gets lost and the virtual keyboard gets disappeared. This happens only the first time I launch the app. After it happens once it never happens again until I leave the app. But the next time I launch the app it happens again the first time I enter a character in text field.
Tested on Android 4.0.4. It does not happen on 4.4.2.

Answer (score 1):

you have to change the Activity's "Window soft input mode" in the Android Manifest, to "adjustPan".